# I am not sure what's happening here

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

[image]

I can't enter edit mode when this happens, and the material preview becomes weird as well. How do I get out of this?

Comment: Please post a complete screenshot of your user interface. There's currently not enough information for use to identify the issue.